# Android - how to display number of likes in a post using firebase

Tags: android, firebase, count, facebook-like

i want to print the total no of likes for particular post.**but it gives me an error in this code`long numOfLikes = dataSnapshot.child("likes").getValue(Long.class);` and the error is  Attempt to invoke virtual method 'long java.lang.Long.longValue()' on a null object reference**
[image]

my code is

```
 private void onLikeClicked(View v) {
    boolean isLiked = !btnLike.isSelected();
    final String currentUserKey = User.currentKey();

    DatabaseReference likes = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(kDataLikeKey);
    DatabaseReference curLike = likes.child(mPostRef.getKey()).child(currentUserKey).child("likes");
    likes.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            long numLikes = 0;
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                boolean isLiked = !btnLike.isSelected();
                if (isLiked) {
                    //If already liked then user wants to unlike the post
                    likes.setValue(numLikes - 1);
                }
            } else {

                //If not liked already then user wants to like the post
                likes.setValue(numLikes + 1);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    // update Model
    curLike.setValue(isLiked);

    // update UI
    btnLike.setSelected(isLiked);
    displayNumberOfLikes();

}
public void displayNumberOfLikes(){
    boolean isLiked = !btnLike.isSelected();
    final String currentUserKey = User.currentKey();

    DatabaseReference likes = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(kDataLikeKey);
    DatabaseReference curLike = likes.child(mPostRef.getKey()).child(currentUserKey).child("likes");
    likes.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener(){
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                long numOfLikes = dataSnapshot.child("likes").getValue(Long.class);
                mlikecnt.setText(""+numOfLikes);
                //Populate numOfLikes on post i.e. textView.setText(""+numOfLikes)
                //This is to check if the user has liked the post or not
                btnLike.setSelected(dataSnapshot.hasChild(currentUserKey));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DatabaseReference likes = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("posts").child("KEY_WHATEVER_YOU_ARE_USING").child("likes");
likes.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
           long numOfLikes = dataSnapshot.getValue(Long.class);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you provide your full database structure ? It will help me to help you.

Comment: @AryaPrabagar i have updated answer please check and let me know your output.

Comment: @AryaPrabagar as my given code is correct and i tried on my system it is working fine. Are you sure, you are getting right key under the node posts in your code,  can log your key in logcat  and verify you are getting right key? because key inside post is the only thing which is dynamic.